# Fedora 8 - out of date?

Tags: centos, fedora, amazon-ec2

We use Fedora 8 (an Amazon EC2 Public Image) for some of our servers. I see that Fedora is at version 20 now, and Fedora 8 is from around 2006/7. What confuses me is that these servers were installed in 2009, so even then this was quite an old version. Does Fedora 8 have longer support? I thought Centos is used for servers as it's more stable, while Fedora is experimental, but maybe that wasn't the case back then.

I wonder if this isn't completely outdated? What are the risks?

---

**Update**

Back in 2009 Amazon EC2 used Fedora 8 as default AMI, and it was not possible to install a newer Fedora release. Apparantly Amazon released updates themselves, so they kept it up to date.

See [http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:H8Gev23IDqkJ:velohacker.com/2009/10/16/ec2-and-fedora-still-stuck-at-fedora-8/+&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aH8Gev23IDqkJ%3avelohacker.com/2009/10/16/ec2-and-fedora-still-stuck-at-fedora-8/+&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life), Fedora 8 is unsupported since 2009. Most packages are outdated, for example Bash, in Fedora 8 it's `3.2` and in modern distros, it's `4.2`. Full list of packages in Fedora 8 is located [here](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/8/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/).

And is it safe? Well, it depends on software running on your servers. I can suppose that devs had eliminated a large number of bugs in for example `Apache`, `iptables` or `openssl` (keyword: `Heartbleed`, but since Fedora 8 is older than 2 years, it shouldn't affect your OS).

Comment: Thanks. I just found the releasepage for Fedora 8, and saw that it was EOL before we installed it. I'm trying to find out why it was used back then. We use them as webservers and databaseservers, so Apache and Iptables are used.

Comment: It turns out that we use this server for legacy php apps that require php 5.2. I'm going to see what websites we can move away from that server to a new instance. Updating might break too many things, while moving stuff one by one is easier undone when it doesn't work.